# how to resolve the docker-compose up command execution

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to test this project https://github.com/saan099/sawtooth-test

But while executing `docker-compose up` command I found this problem:

```
ERROR: Version in "./docker-compose.yaml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

I have tried to change with another version but I still have the same problem. I would be very grateful please if you could help me please.

Those are my docker version and my docker-composer version:

```
>>> ~/sawtooth-test $ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3

>>> ~/sawtooth-test $ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 1.9.0
CPython version: 2.7.12
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

But when I put this docker-compose --version

```
   >>> ~/sawtooth-test $ docker version
    Client:
    Version:      1.13.1
    API version:  1.26
    Go version:   go1.6.2
    Git commit:   092cba3
    Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
    OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

>>> ~/sawtooth-test $ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, share your docker version, worked for me in  Version: 17.12.1-ce
 API version: 1.35
 Go version: go1.10.1
 Git commit: 7390fc6
 Built: Wed Apr 18 01:23:11 2018
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Comment: @Kilian could you please the edited question

Answer (score 7):

Update the first line of your `docker-compose.yml` file to say `version: '3'` instead of `version: '2.1'`

Here is some more information for you pertaining to Docker-Compose versioning.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Answer (score -2):

go and nano to *docker-compose.yaml*

edit  version : '2' to "2"

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

finally should fix your issue